# Unregistered Registration Token in Firebase

Tags: android, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I got unregistered registration token even I am sure my token is correct and I check it in my log I am using master token `FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token`.

Here is my method:

```
private void ConfigureFireBase()
        {

            Task.Run(() => {
                var instanceId = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance;
                Android.Util.Log.Debug("TAG", "{0} {1}", instanceId?.Token?.ToString(), instanceId.GetToken(GetString(Resource.String.gcm_defaultSenderId), Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.InstanceIdScope));

            });

        }
```

I check as well `OnTokenRefresh` method the same token

```
public override void OnTokenRefresh()
        {
            var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
            SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
        }
```

but when I tried in Firebase console it gives me this error message, when I tried in http://pushtry.com/ with the same token I got not **NotRegistered** message

***Note*** when I uninstall the app and install again the token working, but after while I got this error message.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, but could you paraphrase this part "*but when I tried in Firebase console it gives me this error message, when I tried in http://pushtry.com/ with the same token I got not NotRegistered message*". It's a little confusing. Do you mean that it works on Firebase Console, but not when using pushtry.com or vice versa?

Comment: no it dosnt work in both but I display the message in both side , in firebase console it says Unregistered Registration Token , even this token I got from OnTokenRefresh  method  so it should be refreshed one

Comment: The same is hapening with me. I am using Xamarin too. Have you managed to solve the issue?

Comment: yea this issue in debug mode only I will provide full answer soon

Comment: any update on this ? I'm facing the same issue in Xamarin

Comment: yea please check my answer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The reason why this issue fired cause  that token is unregistered

> ```
> The registration token may change when:
>
> The app deletes Instance ID
> The app is restored on a new device
> The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
> The user clears app data.
> ```

[Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-device#access_the_registration_token)

and this happen in debug mode only so dont worry in release mode every thing will be fine.

**How you can fix the issue ?**

its easy just force to refresh token call this method in your landing activity (MainActivity , Login ) , this method force firebase to call `OnTokenRefresh()`

```
private void ConfigureFireBase()
        {

#if DEBUG

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var instanceId = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance;
                instanceId.DeleteInstanceId();
                Android.Util.Log.Debug("TAG", "{0} {1}", instanceId?.Token?.ToString(), instanceId.GetToken(GetString(Resource.String.gcm_defaultSenderId), Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.InstanceIdScope));

            });

            // For debug mode only - will accept the HTTPS certificate of Test/Dev server, as the HTTPS certificate is invalid /not trusted
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, certificate, chain, errors) => true;


#endif
        }
```

Hope this help any one face same issue

Comment: It looks like the call to `DeleteInstanceId()` will cause the `FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token` to return `null` for a short period, but it will also trigger `OnTokenRefresh()` for the  `FirebaseInstanceIdService` which will then populate the `FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token` with the new registered token. For me the call to `FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.GetToken(...)` was irrelevant and would just return an unregistered token, different from the `FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token` (using Firebase v42.1021.1).

Comment: I added it in the OnCreate of Application, to make sure it is excuted before most functions been called.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had used Emulator and the Firewall was blocking it. I used my mobile, enabled the developer options and it got worked.

Hope this helps.