# Firebase notifications not received on Android app

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send notifications from Firebase to an Android mobile app developed in Visual Studio 2015.

I tried to implement each step that is presented in [this tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/), but I still can't receive notifications.

One weird thing that I noticed is related to this part of the tutorial:

```
Log.Debug(TAG, "google app id: " + Resource.String.google_app_id);
    The google_app_id value logged to the output window should match the mobilesdk_app_id value recorded in google-services.json.
```

The result of the log that I quotted above doesn't match the mobilesdk_app_id value recorded in google-services.json, although I made every step presented in the tutorial.

Also, when I try to send notification that has the target set to "single device" and I write in the FCM registration token the result of the FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token, the message status is "failed" (Unregistered registration token).

How can I fix this issues?

Later edit:
The difference between the [possible duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537072/unregistered-registration-token-in-firebase) and mine is that my FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token is not equal to mobilesdk_app_id value recorded in google-services.json.

Any ideas?

Content of manifest file (between application tags):

```
<application android:label="RTSD_Firebase">
<receiver
android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
android:exported="false" />
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]  to illustrate what you have done so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unregistered Registration Token in Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537072/unregistered-registration-token-in-firebase)

Comment: The difference in `google_app_id` is because the log call prints the integer resource id of the `google_app_id` string resource. The line in the tutorial should be `Log.Debug(TAG, "google app id: " + GetString(Resource.String.google_app_id));`, which will most likely print the correct app id.

Comment: @CatalinMiron Are you sure that you added the `<receiver>` tags in AndroidManifest.xml inside the `<application>` tags? I made that mistake and the notifications were not coming through, and Firebase console showed the "unregistered registration token" error.

Comment: @LauriKoskela Thanks for your replies. I used "Log.Debug(TAG, "google app id: " + GetString(Resource.String.google_app_id));" and it prints the right string, so there's no problem with google_app_id. The <receiver> tags are inside <application> tags. I added the content of manifest file in the post